# CMake can not find g++ compiler on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, g++

I have a CMake project I want to compile with g++. The project compiles and runs on Linux. Now I am trying to get it working on Windows.

For that reason, I installed MinGW and added it to the PATH and I am using Git Bash. In order to force CMake to use g++ I added these env variables:

```
CC = C:\MinGW\bin\gcc
CXX = C:\MinGW\bin\g++
```

[image: Git Bash output for printenv]

But when I run CMake it does not detect any compilers and tells me:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unkown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unkown
```

[image: CMake can not find the C and CXX compiler]

I created a super basic example on github which I would like to get running on Windows + MinGw: https://github.com/j-o-d-o/Basic-CMake-Project

How can I use the env variables in windows to force CMake to use g++ and gcc compiler?

Comment: After adding the env variables, it helps to close the current terminal and open a new one.

Comment: Did you restart your terminal after changing `PATH`? If you `echo $PATH` in bash, is MingW's `bin` directory there?

Comment: @molbdnilo: The OP didn't change the PATH variable.

Comment: @IInspectable That’s not how I interpret ”added it to the path”.

Comment: What I mean by "added it to the path" is I added "C:\MinGW\bin" and "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin" to PATH. I restarted my machine afterward just in case. When `echo $PATH` these two paths are showing up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to add `-G "MinGW Makefiles"` to the CMake command.

I check if I am on Windows and if yes, I add the parameter to the CMake command in the shell script. 
I also need to use `mingw32-make` instead of `make` when I am on Windows.

There are some other issues now, but it resolves the issue/question I have posted.